# HDInsight Server Locally multi-node | NOT on Azure

Tags: azure, hadoop, distributed, windows-server, azure-hdinsight

I am confused.

Can you install HDInsight Server (**multiple nodes**) **locally**, NOT on Azure?

I don't want to install Hortonworks (I know that HDInsight uses their distribution).

Also, I don't want to install any kind of emulator or developer preview with one node.

Again, I would like to install HDInsight on my windows servers on PRODUCTION, how can I do that?

Comment: Why not going for the original hadoop version?

Comment: I would like to run Hadoop on windows. I don't want to install Horton Windows distribution. I want to get all the goodies that Azuer offers for HDInsight but I want it on my servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chicago, I don't think this is possible. HDInsight is a service offered as part of the public Azure offering. If you want to install multiple nodes locally you will need to go with Hortonworks or the Apache Hadoop distribution.

Comment: That's what I thought. Hortonworks is great but they are missing all the UI components for Windows installation. Also installer is buggy ((